# Charset making me confuse

Tags: java, character-encoding, ascii

A simple decryption method for php, works well and generates output correctly. Here's the code.

```
function decryption($Str)
{
  $key = "huasHIYhkasdho1";
  $Newstr="";
  $lenKey=strlen($key);
  $KeyPos=1;
  $LenStr=strlen($Str);
  $str=strrev($Str);
  for ($x=$LenStr; $x>=1; $x--)
  {
    //Step(-1); // WARNING: assuming Step is an external function
    $DecCharNum=ord(substr($str,$x-1,1))-ord(substr($key,$KeyPos-1,1)) + 256;
    $Newstr.=chr($DecCharNum % 256);
    $KeyPos++;
    if ($KeyPos > $lenKey)
    {
      $KeyPos=1;
    }
  }
  $Newstr=strrev($Newstr);
  return $Newstr;
}
```

But I'm trying to convert it to java. Mostly i had done, but what problem am facing is the Charset, I'm not able to figure out the Charset the String passed in the above method. Here's the image of the String which i need to decrypt.

This image is the actual snapshot taken in Windows OS(Windows7).
[image]

Java code for the same

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileToArrayOfBytes
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream=null;

        File file = new File("Report.txt");

        String key = "huasHIYhkasdho1";
        String Newstr = "";
        int lenKey = key.length();
        System.out.println("Key Length : "+lenKey);
        int KeyPos=1;
        byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        try {
        //convert file into array of bytes
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        fileInputStream.read(bFile);
        fileInputStream.close();
        System.out.println("bFile length : "+bFile.length);
        int LenStr=bFile.length;        
        System.out.println("String Length : "+LenStr);      
        for (int x = bFile.length; x > 0; x--)
        {
            System.out.println("========================================");
        int DecCharNum = ( (int)bFile[x-1] ) - ( (int)key.charAt(KeyPos-1) ) + 256;
            System.out.println("sub 1 = "+ (char)bFile[x-1]);
            System.out.println("sub 2 = " + key.charAt(KeyPos-1));
        System.out.println("ord 1 = " + (int)bFile[x-1]);
        System.out.println("ord 2 = " + (int)key.charAt(KeyPos-1));
        System.out.println("Sub = "+DecCharNum);            
        Newstr += (char) (DecCharNum % 256);
        System.out.println("Dec Value = "+DecCharNum);
        System.out.println("New String = "+ Newstr );

        KeyPos++;
        System.out.println("Position "+KeyPos);

        if (KeyPos > lenKey)
        {
        System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        KeyPos=1;
            System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        }
        System.out.println("========================================");
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

output for the above code is

```
Key Length : 15
bFile length : 26
String Length : 26
========================================
sub 1 = 

sub 2 = h
ord 1 = 10
ord 2 = 104
Sub = 162
Dec Value = 162
New String = ¢
Position 2
========================================
========================================
sub 1 = ﾓ
sub 2 = u
ord 1 = -109
ord 2 = 117
Sub = 30
Dec Value = 30
New String = ¢
Position 3
========================================
========================================
sub 1 = ﾛ
sub 2 = a
ord 1 = -101
ord 2 = 97
Sub = 58
Dec Value = 58
New String = ¢:
Position 4
========================================
========================================
sub 1 = ﾙ
sub 2 = s
ord 1 = -103
ord 2 = 115
Sub = 38
Dec Value = 38
New String = ¢:&
Position 5
========================================
========================================
sub 1 = ﾛ
sub 2 = H
ord 1 = -101
ord 2 = 72
Sub = 83
Dec Value = 83
New String = ¢:&S
Position 6
========================================
========================================
sub 1 = ﾏ
sub 2 = I
ord 1 = -113
ord 2 = 73
Sub = 70
Dec Value = 70
New String = ¢:&SF
Position 7
========================================
========================================
sub 1 = z
sub 2 = Y
ord 1 = 122
ord 2 = 89
Sub = 289
Dec Value = 289
New String = ¢:&SF!
Position 8
========================================
========================================
sub 1 = ﾫ
sub 2 = h
ord 1 = -85
ord 2 = 104
Sub = 67
Dec Value = 67
New String = ¢:&SF!C
Position 9
========================================
========================================
sub 1 = ﾒ
sub 2 = k
ord 1 = -110
ord 2 = 107
Sub = 39
Dec Value = 39
New String = ¢:&SF!C'
Position 10
========================================
========================================
sub 1 = ﾦ
sub 2 = a
ord 1 = -90
ord 2 = 97
Sub = 69
Dec Value = 69
New String = ¢:&SF!C'E
Position 11
========================================
========================================
sub 1 = ﾭ
sub 2 = s
ord 1 = -83
ord 2 = 115
Sub = 58
Dec Value = 58
New String = ¢:&SF!C'E:
Position 12
========================================
========================================
sub 1 = s
sub 2 = d
ord 1 = 115
ord 2 = 100
Sub = 271
Dec Value = 271
New String = ¢:&SF!C'E:
Position 13
========================================
========================================
sub 1 = ﾠ
sub 2 = h
ord 1 = -96
ord 2 = 104
Sub = 56
Dec Value = 56
New String = ¢:&SF!C'E:8
Position 14
========================================
========================================
sub 1 = ﾠ
sub 2 = o
ord 1 = -96
ord 2 = 111
Sub = 49
Dec Value = 49
New String = ¢:&SF!C'E:81
Position 15
========================================
========================================
sub 1 = ﾔ
sub 2 = 1
ord 1 = -108
ord 2 = 49
Sub = 99
Dec Value = 99
New String = ¢:&SF!C'E:81c
Position 16
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
========================================
========================================
sub 1 = ﾣ
sub 2 = h
ord 1 = -93
ord 2 = 104
Sub = 59
Dec Value = 59
New String = ¢:&SF!C'E:81c;
Position 2
========================================
========================================
sub 1 = ﾗ
sub 2 = u
ord 1 = -105
ord 2 = 117
Sub = 34
Dec Value = 34
New String = ¢:&SF!C'E:81c;"
Position 3
========================================
========================================
sub 1 = ﾱ
sub 2 = a
ord 1 = -79
ord 2 = 97
Sub = 80
Dec Value = 80
New String = ¢:&SF!C'E:81c;"P
Position 4
========================================
========================================
sub 1 = ﾬ
sub 2 = s
ord 1 = -84
ord 2 = 115
Sub = 57
Dec Value = 57
New String = ¢:&SF!C'E:81c;"P9
Position 5
========================================
========================================
sub 1 = ﾋ
sub 2 = H
ord 1 = -117
ord 2 = 72
Sub = 67
Dec Value = 67
New String = ¢:&SF!C'E:81c;"P9C
Position 6
========================================
========================================
sub 1 = y
sub 2 = I
ord 1 = 121
ord 2 = 73
Sub = 304
Dec Value = 304
New String = ¢:&SF!C'E:81c;"P9C0
Position 7
========================================
========================================
sub 1 = y
sub 2 = Y
ord 1 = 121
ord 2 = 89
Sub = 288
Dec Value = 288
New String = ¢:&SF!C'E:81c;"P9C0 
Position 8
========================================
========================================
sub 1 = ﾦ
sub 2 = h
ord 1 = -90
ord 2 = 104
Sub = 62
Dec Value = 62
New String = ¢:&SF!C'E:81c;"P9C0 >
Position 9
========================================
========================================
sub 1 = ﾕ
sub 2 = k
ord 1 = -107
ord 2 = 107
Sub = 42
Dec Value = 42
New String = ¢:&SF!C'E:81c;"P9C0 >*
Position 10
========================================
========================================
sub 1 = ﾪ
sub 2 = a
ord 1 = -86
ord 2 = 97
Sub = 73
Dec Value = 73
New String = ¢:&SF!C'E:81c;"P9C0 >*I
Position 11
========================================
========================================
sub 1 = ﾝ
sub 2 = s
ord 1 = -99
ord 2 = 115
Sub = 42
Dec Value = 42
New String = ¢:&SF!C'E:81c;"P9C0 >*I*
Position 12
========================================
Done
```

The output i needed for the above code is : `201BF2811EB18006FD2013455`

Please help me to figure out the problem, I know the problem is the Charset used, I am not able to figure it out what to do for correct output.

Comment: Make this an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) by including the encoded string as a variable. Also notice that [`FileInputStream.read`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28byte[]%29) will not neccessarily read all bytes from the file. It may well read less. Check out [`DataInputStream.readFully`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readFully%28byte[]%29), but be aware that the file length reported might be wrong, e.g. if the file is currently being written to or is not a regular file.

Comment: I apologize for this, but i thought it would be necessary to find the problem with my code. I will look forward into it. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Can anyone tell the charset used in the pic
[link] (http://i41.tinypic.com/w9h2kj.png) [/link]

Comment: http://ideone.com/uLJQh0 has the PHP example. Including one non-ASCII symbol before the quoted sequence, namely `\x97`. In Latin1 this isn't assigned, in Windows 1252 this is the em dash, Unicode calls this [“end of guarded area”](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/97/index.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has nothing at all to do with charsets. You're reading your input as bytes, not characters, and the expected output is mostly ASCII. And the way you treat it, translating between `byte` and `char`, you're traing the output as ISO-8859-1, just as PHP usually does.

The core of the problem is direction. The PHP code reverses the string, then iterates over the input from back to front, then reverses the result. Which amounts to the same as iterating over the input from front to back. But you kept the iteration back to front, while at the same time not porting the `strrev` calls. Change your loop to

```java
for (int x = 1; x <= bFile.length; x++)
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: Stll I'am not able to find solution for the above problem, can you help me to figure it out